# Can I run Google colaboratory locally?

Tags: amazon-redshift, vpn, google-colaboratory

At my company, most of our databases are stored on redshift servers that can only be accessed by connecting to the company VPN.

Additionally, most of our internal company packages can only be run in conjunction with the VPN. I would therefore like to create google colab documents that I can share with my co-workers but that rely on locally installed packages and an active connection to the VPN.

Is that possible / is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colab now supports execution with local backends! You can get started by following these instructions: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

By default, Colab stores all code cell outputs in Google Drive. If your local connection will access sensitive data and you would like to omit these, you can select "Omit code cell output when saving this notebook" when connecting to your local runtime.